# How do I open ports on a docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using a docker file as shown here, in my project :

https://github.com/jamiepratt/embedded-repl/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

I start the container with:

`docker-compose up app`

But cannot connect to the socket. Can't see what I am doing wrong.

The ports are not accessible either on my local system or when I put the docker container on a server.

After `docker-compose up app` I see the following:

```
 docker container ls
 CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                                NAMES
 886341940c74   embedded-repl_app                "entrypoint java -ja…"   30 minutes ago   Up 30 minutes   0.0.0.0:2001->54654/tcp, :::2001->54654/tcp                                          embedded-repl_app_1
```

But then when I try to telnet:

```
telnet localhost 2001
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be mistaken, but this looks like an issue with the application itself closing connections.

> ```
> Connected to localhost.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> ```

These lines above show that telnet is connecting through to docker, however the application is then closing the connection.